# Android Studio set png-file from getFilesDir() in XML (srccompat)

Tags: java, android, xml, attributes

How can I set the app:srcCompat-attribute of my ImageView in Android Studio to a file from the locale directory of the device (getFilesDir())? I know programmatically getFilesDir() returns the local directory but as I need to set a png file, which is replaced during runtime and should be shown inside the ImageView, I need to set the correct path in srcCompat. Storing the image in drawable-directory is not sufficient as its files cannot be written on during runtime unfortunately ...

Comment: Use an image-loading library: Glide, Picasso, Coil, etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.